# GeneXus 15 U2 Preview - File Data Type has changed

Tags: genexus

Apparently in this version of GeneXus, how the File Data Type works has changed. Right or wrong, previously you could return the contents of the `&File` variable by saying:

```
&Var = &File.Source
```

In GeneXus 15 this now returns blank. Now, the `.Source` is for assigning only - you cannot read it any longer.

We have to scan our KBs for this case and replace the code accordingly, but we are looking for an easy way to find these cases.  Does anyone know how to get a list of objects that use at least one variable that is a File Data Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of at least two ways to search for the `Source` property:

1. Search for ".source" in the generated source files
2. Export all your KB objects and search inside the .xpz file (it is just a renamed .zip containing a .xml)